# PHP: getting variables for many rows in a databse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to send a PHP variable ID thats saved in a database to a page displaying Google Map markers using Javascript. I have created a list to display what is displayed when the map marker is clicked in PHP/HTML:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM places");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<div class='place-details' id='place-details' style='display: none'>";
            echo "<table class='table'>";
            echo "<tr><th>Name: </th><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>Details: </th><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo"</table>";
            echo "<td><a href='details.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>View</a></td></div>";
        }
```

In the Javascript, I am using clone() to display this list in each marker:

```
var places = $("#place-details").clone().show();

google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(places[0]);
        infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        map.setZoom(10);
    });
```

The "id" is created automatically and it a Unique Key with Auto increment. The problem is, when the page loads and the event markers are clicked, they all show the data from the first row id, rather than each one's own id- thus displaying only the information saved in the first row only.

UPDATE:

```
for (var i in markers)
{
    markers[i].setMap(null);
}

markers[i] = marker;
```

And its all inside the function:

```
place_info.parseData = function(data)
{
    ......
}
```

Comment: in the js event you have a variable called `i`. where is defined? if you are inside a loop you should use another way to bind the click callback

Comment: I've updated the original question for this

Answer (score 0):

You're only using `places[0]`. `var places` is an array of elements, and therefore, you must loop through those elements. I'm assuming the var `i` is generated from a loop, try `setContent(places[i]);`.

Using `places.length` as the upper bound in your loop is probably the better route.

It's also bad practice to put the same `id` attribute on multiple elements. Use a CSS class and the corresponding selector to reference multiple elements that share common content or properties.

Comment: setContent(places[i]); has a similar problem, except it only displays the first row in the DB on its corresponding marker. But when the other markers are clicked, they come up empty.

Comment: And if you use a CSS selector instead of id attribute?

Comment: How would a CSS selector work though? I plan on using the ID of each row so that it can be passed to the url and a specific place details can be viewed on another page. So for example, when the view button is clicked, with the row with id=6, it will pass to the url: "http://............/details.php?id=6

Comment: Set an attribute like `idx="6"`. Then getting the attribute for each: `places[i].attr('idx')`

Comment: Really, the "id" that I'm talking about is the HTML `id` attribute, not the "id" you're injecting into the link URL.

Comment: So something like: echo "<div class='place-details' id='6' style='display: none'>";, and  infowindow.setContent(eventList[i].attr('id')); ????

Comment: Basically, but be careful using the `id` HTML attribute. Browsers will use that attribute as an identifier. I would recommend using a user-defined attribute like `idx` or `x-id` rather than the reserved `id` attribute.

Comment: Yeah I have tried a few variations of this but when the markers a re clicked, nothing comes up, not even a blank info window.